# Summing up cohort behavior cumulatively by date ranges without offsets in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I think this problem, when solved by creating additional charts with offsets, is easy. I want to cut out the middle man and not use offsets (unless they are useful to the answer). I have data for daily cohorts and I know specific information about their behavior 1 day later, 2 days, 3 days ect.[image: current data (Example)]

Now it is rather easy to make a waterfall chart of day by day activity like so...[image]

What I want to do is skip this step (directly above, the waterfall chart) in hopes of shrinking my current workbook by a substantial amount. You can imagine having simply 1 year of data across multiple channels measuring even 1 aspect of behaviors can account for a lot of data and pivot charts. Also, btw, I have the top chart as a pivot thus allowing this to be hands off when calculating what I am looking for.

[image]
What I seek - I look to further construct groups of days as *other* cohorts to examine (for example, say, 1/1 - 1/5) and see what their activity has been in a cumulative fashion since then. To be more specific, I want a table that will show cohort 1/1-1/5's activity in the date range 1/1-1/5 (11) and then their activity from 1/1-1/9 (24, an additional 13 "behavior points" summed).

So far, as I said, my current solution involves the "blue arrow" schematic where an additional table is constructed and I can sum on, essentially, rectangles build by using OFFSET on sell ranges with the MATCH function. I am stumped with how to go about this without the additional charts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to collaborate on a solution. I am told that it will be highly inefficient at scale but it gets the job done. It ss less automation-friendly but can be formulated to capture data not currently present on a, say, a pivot table that you call to update later by extending the area that the formula works on.

[image]

Formula in in I31:

```
=SUM(IF(($C$1:$O$1+OFFSET($B$2,$G31-$B$2,0):OFFSET($B$2,$H31-$B$2,0))>=I$29,OFFSET($C$2,$G31-$B$2,0):OFFSET($O$2,$H31-$B$2,0)))-SUM(IF(($C$1:$O$1+OFFSET($B$2,$G31-$B$2,0):OFFSET($B$2,$H31-$B$2,0))>I$30,OFFSET($C$2,$G31-$B$2,0):OFFSET($O$2,$H31-$B$2,0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

VBA would better for this, but use this formula in C30:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(SUMIF(OFFSET(OFFSET($B$1,$A30-MIN($B$2:$B$10),MIN($B$2:$B$10)-$A30+DAY(C$28)),SEQUENCE($B30-$A30+1),IF(COLUMN(OFFSET($B$1,$A30-MIN($B$2:$B$10),MIN($B$2:$B$10)-$A30+DAY(C$28)))-SEQUENCE($B30-$A30+1,,0)>COLUMN($B$1),0-SEQUENCE($B30-$A30+1,,0),COLUMN($B$1)-COLUMN(OFFSET($B$1,$A30-MIN($B$2:$B$10),MIN($B$2:$B$10)-$A30+DAY(C$28)))+1),1,IF(COLUMN(OFFSET($B$1,$A30-MIN($B$2:$B$10),MIN($B$2:$B$10)-$A30+DAY(C$28)))-SEQUENCE($B30-$A30+1,,0)<=COLUMN($B$1),(C$29-C$28+1)-SEQUENCE($B30-$A30+1,,-(COLUMN(OFFSET($B$1,$A30-MIN($B$2:$B$10),MIN($B$2:$B$10)-$A30+DAY(C$28)))-COLUMN($B$1)-1)),C$29-C$28+1)),"<>")),0)
```

and this in D30:

```
=C30+SUM(SUMIF(OFFSET(OFFSET($B$1,$A30-MIN($B$2:$B$10),MIN($B$2:$B$10)-$A30+DAY(D$28)),SEQUENCE($B30-$A30+1),IF(COLUMN(OFFSET($B$1,$A30-MIN($B$2:$B$10),MIN($B$2:$B$10)-$A30+DAY(D$28)))-SEQUENCE($B30-$A30+1,,0)>COLUMN($B$1),0-SEQUENCE($B30-$A30+1,,0),COLUMN($B$1)-COLUMN(OFFSET($B$1,$A30-MIN($B$2:$B$10),MIN($B$2:$B$10)-$A30+DAY(D$28)))+1),1,IF(COLUMN(OFFSET($B$1,$A30-MIN($B$2:$B$10),MIN($B$2:$B$10)-$A30+DAY(D$28)))-SEQUENCE($B30-$A30+1,,0)<=COLUMN($B$1),(D$29-D$28+1)-SEQUENCE($B30-$A30+1,,-(COLUMN(OFFSET($B$1,$A30-MIN($B$2:$B$10),MIN($B$2:$B$10)-$A30+DAY(D$28)))-COLUMN($B$1)-1)),D$29-D$28+1)),"<>"))
```

And copy both down.

If one does not have the dynamic Array formula `SEQUENCE()` then replace all the `SEQUENCE($B30-$A30+1)` and `SEQUENCE($B30-$A30+1,,0)` with `ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,$B30-$A30+1))` and `(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,$B30-$A30+1))-1)` Respectively, and use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Was worried this was a tough problem without VBA. I am new to excel but have background knowledge in other languages and am under the tutelage of a power user so I have advanced quickly. Would you happen to know of good VBA sources? Thanks, will try these functions out now. I do not have sequence either. Will look up how to get it but, please, feel free to direct to sources on that if you have any.

Comment: `SEQUENCE()` is only available with a subscription version of Office 365.  As to vba, the internet and trial and error are the best teachers.  Break down the steps and google them, then try to put the steps together.  When you get stuck bring the code and a description of the error and ask a new question relating to those.